# Datadog crash reporting: Adding version code and other tags to crashes

Tags: android, datadog

Crash reports in Datadog can be configured to include tags such as environment (env), service, and version. How can I include a tag for version_code here?

For Datadog logging you can add your own tags, but these are not sent in when the app is crashing.